# 'b' в dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Существует некий код, который работает с redis и возвращает `l = {b'my_key_1': b'15', b'another_key': b'557', b'and_another_key': b'272'}` по запросу `hgetall`. На сколько я понимаю, b означает bytes. Мне из этого нужно получить обычный dictionary в utf-8 `{'my_key_1': '15', 'another_key': '557', 'and_another_key': '272'}` . Для этого мне приходится делать так: `data = {key.decode('utf-8'): value.decode('utf-8') for (key, value) in l.items()}`

Собственно вопрос: А есть ли способ как-то в python3 сказать, что мне по дефолту всё что в скрипте происходит, нужно в utf-8 ? В python2, например, он возвращает всё так, как нужно.

Comment: А причем тут интерпретатор, если структуру вам возвращает сторонняя библиотека?

Comment: Скорее всего, в python2 возвращаются те же самые bytes, а вы этого просто не заметили. Bytes в python3 — это то же самое, что и str в python2

Comment: @Lecron при том, что одна и та же сторонняя библиотека в одном случае возвращает один тип данных, а в другом - иной.

Comment: @andreymal допустим. Как мне в итоге получать словарь "без б"? В скрипте много вызовов `hgetall` и постоянно конвертировать вот тем способом что я показал - как-то не очень.

Comment: @whoknow у `redis-py` есть опция `decode_responses`

Comment: @andreymal премного благодарен ^_^

Comment: «в одном случае возвращает один тип данных, а в другом - иной» — как я заметил выше, скорее всего это не так, просто во втором питоне возле bytes не стоит буковка 'б'